# What's the JDO equivalent of the JPA @PersistenceContext annotation

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jdo

In JPA, you can inject an `EntityManager` with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

What is the JDO equivalent of this for a `PersistenceManager`?

```
@????
private PersistenceManager persistenceManager;
```

Comment: There is none since @PersistenceContext is handled by a managed environment (e.g J2EE, Spring, Guice) and not by the persistence handler. That ought to be handled by the JEE spec, not by the persistence spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard equivalent AFAIK. But you could use [Guice](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/unit-testing-with-jdo-persistencemanager-injected-via-guice/) or [Spring JDO Support](http://notwastingtime.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-set-up-spring-3-in-google-app.html).